# Работа с элементами матрицы 3х3 в PHP

Tags: матрицы, html, php

Доброго времени суток.

Нужна помощь. Надо сделать программу, где 2 файла - main.html и index.php
В main.html форма получает введенные пользователем 9 элементов матрицы 3х3 и 3 элемента матрицы 3х1. Эти данные далее отправляются в index.php и там 2 матрицы должны умножиться друг на друга.

Поиски в гугле результатов не дали. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

**Обновление**

Я вот понять не могу именно, как взаимодействовать с элементами массива-матрицы как с самостоятельными частицами.

Код:

```
<h2>Матрица 3х1</h2>
    <form action = "index.php" method = "POST">
    <p><strong>Введите a11: </strong></p>
    a11 = <input type = "text" name = "a1" value = "">
    <p><strong>Введите a21: </strong></p>
    a21 = <input type = "text" name = "a2" value = "">
    <p><strong>Введите a31: </strong></p>
    a31 = <input type = "text" name = "a3" value = "">
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Отправить!">
```

Только форму в html, точно так же, как 3х1.

Comment: то есть, у вас первая матрица имеет 3 столбца и 3 строки, а вторая 1 столбец и 3 строки?

Comment: Вы правы, да.

Comment: Можете показать, как пользователь вводит значения (html-код покажите)?

Comment: только форму в html, точно также как 3х1

Comment: А матрица 3x3, я так понимаю, у вас уже есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаете аналогичным образом элементы матрицы 3х3 `b11,b12...b33` и в `index.php` производите умножение. Если опустить валидацию данных, то примерно так

```
$c11 = $_POST['b11']*$_POST['a1'] + $_POST['b12']*$_POST['a2'] + $_POST['b13']*$_POST['a3'];

$c21 = $_POST['b21']*$_POST['a1'] + $_POST['b22']*$_POST['a2'] + $_POST['b23']*$_POST['a3'];

$c31 = $_POST['b31']*$_POST['a1'] + $_POST['b32']*$_POST['a2'] + $_POST['b33']*$_POST['a3'];
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, запомню